# Headset microphone is not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have an ASUS VivoBook S5402ZA laptop with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04. The internal microphone works, but the headset microphone does not. If I connect the headset via a USB hub with a jack, it starts detecting the microphone. I have another ASUS ROG series laptop and when I plug in the headset it asks me which mode I want to use the headset or headphones in and the microphone works perfectly fine. When I disable HD Audio support in the BIOS of this ROG laptop, it no longer prompts for the mode. On my Vivobook I have a similar setting in the BIOS, but switching it doesn't help. On Windows, when I plug in a headset, the HD Audio console pops up.

Headphones Stereo microphone is listed even if no headset is plugged in, and it doesn't work when I plug in a headset.

I've already tried to edit file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. I've been adding values from here https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html (all, where I have seen headset, microphone or alc294 but it didn't help).

The same issue on Fedora and Manjaro.

```
Linux Asus-VivoBookS5402ZA 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Codec: Realtek ALC294
```

Pavucontrol input devices:

[image: Pavucontrol input devices]

Alsa-info log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vkV2tlT1TfbKNF72DY8To7TpGo9G53ba/view?usp=sharing